# Would you please let me know if there will be a quiz on (day)? or Would you please let me know if it will be a quiz on (day)?

Tags: sentence-construction

Would you please let me know if there will be a quiz on (day)?  or Would you please let me know if it will be a quiz on (day)?

what is the correct way to ask?

Answer (score 1):

*It* can be a dummy subject in some contexts; but not, as far as I can think, where the statement is about the existence of something.

Here, *it* would have to refer to something. "... if it will be a quiz ... " only makes sense if we already know what "it" refers to, eg "I know that you hold a social event every night of the week. Would you let me know if it will be a quiz on ... "

So you need "if there will be" in your request.

Comment: Your answer is completely understandable to me but I doubt I would have got[ten]  it were I an ELLer.